# pnpm build fails after loading env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pnpm

I can successfully run a project on a different computer, but on this particular computer I can not get pnpm to run, and I get no errors. The compile fails here and then does nothing else. It doesn't give me any errors or anything. It's just stuck after ready / info just after loading the env file. I know my env file is correct because it runs on a different computer.

[image]

I've tried everything!

- reinstalled windows from scratch!
- removed node_modules files, cleared with pnpm store prune
- tried windows terminal and regular terminal.

Anything else I should try? How do I get more verbose error logging!?